# Retrieving data in Symfony using the model class

Tags: php, symfony1, model, doctrine

Let's say I have a model `Ecosystem` automatically generated with symfony from my `schema.yml`. At some point in the code, I would like to retrieve records from the table.

I know there are some ways to do this with Doctrine/Propel classes, but, is there a way of doing it with directly the model? I've been thinking in something like this:

```
$ecosystem = new Ecosystem();
$records = $ecosystem->find(...);
```

By the way, which is the preferred method to do this kind of things?

I've been developing with CakePHP and making queries directly with Doctrine doesn't seem natural to me. What if I decide to change to Propel tomorrow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose your model is `Ecosystem`.
Doctrine autogenerates two model classes for you:

1. `Ecosystem` (defined in `Ecosystem.class.php`) — objects of this class are actual `ecosystem` entities
2. `EcoSystemTable` (defined in `EcosystemTable.class.php`) — singleton class to provide **management** over `Ecosystem` entities

This why all the entity management functionality is done with `*Table` classes. How to get them?

```
Doctrine::getTable('Ecosystem')
```

or

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('Ecosystem')
```

or

```
EcosystemTable::getInstance()
```

or

```
$obj->getTable(); // where $obj is instance of Doctrine_Record
```

**Further reading:**

- [Doctrine_Record API (ver 1.2)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html)
- [Doctrine_Table API (ver 1.2)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_table.html)
- [Practical symfony. Day 6: More with the Model](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/06)

Answer (score 1):

Of cause you can do that, just you *Table class methods, for example:
$record = Doctrine::getTable('Ecosystem')->find(1) will return a record with id = 1. You can read more about available finders here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:magic-finders
I think you can safely get away without manually writing DQL queries, unless you care about performance.

Comment: I meant making queries even without using Doctrine classes. For instance, in CakePHP you can make queries like this `$ecosystem->findById(1)`

Comment: @elitalon: in your example Ecosystem is also a doctrine class (extends Doctrine_Table).